# How to get rid of extra + sign in print statement, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

```
print('2**', n, ' + ', sep='', end='')
```

Hi the print statement above is in a loop so the output ends up being

```
2 ** 10 + 2 ** 7 + 2 ** 6 + 2 ** 4 + 2 ** 1 +
```

I need to get rid of the last plus in the statement but have no idea how to go about doing so.

Comment: Preparing a string list containing all the elements and then call `' + '.join(elements)` on it will do the trick.

Comment: For example `print(' + '.join(['2 ** %s' % n for n in somelist]))`. `.join` will only add its string between adjecent elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you separate the exponents, as you have probably done, you can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> exponents = (10, 7, 6, 4, 1)
>>> print(' + '.join('2**{}'.format(n) for n in exponents))
2**10 + 2**7 + 2**6 + 2**4 + 2**1
```

That will work in both Python 2 & 3. You can also use the `print()` function with the `sep` argument:

```
>>> print(*('2**{}'.format(n) for n in exponents), sep=' + ')
2**10 + 2**7 + 2**6 + 2**4 + 2**1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty 'common' 'problem', and it is often solved by using ''.join method. I assume that you've a list of integers, so all you need to do is:

```
powers = [10, 7, 6, 4]
print(' + '.join(['2 ** {n}'.format(n= n) for n in powers]))
```

Comment: No need for `str(n)` here - `str.format` will use `str` by default for its inputs....

Answer (score 0):

You can store the string to be printed in a variable in the loop and then after the loop ends, remove the extra plus by slicing using `to_print[:len(to_print)-1]`
And then print to_print.
Here to_print is the text you need to store in the loop Instead of printing it and then print it at the end after slicing it as I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

Either check if you're at the last element and use a different print statement (without the final `'+'`), or construct your output in a list first and join the list before printing.

```
output = []
some_loop:
    output.append('2**%i' % n)

print(' + '.join(output))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, and adapting it to your loop length

```
n = 1
for i in range(0,10):
    if i < 9:
        print('2**', n, ' + ', sep='', end = '')
    else:
        print('2**', n, sep='', end = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

[join()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) helps a lot in this case:

```
exponents = [10, 7, 6, 4, 1]
out = []
for n in exponents:
   out.append('2 ** %d' % n)
print ' + '.join(out)
```